# how to set key and value with json object in ng-options in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a json object with name optionData as

```
{
 "1": "प्रदेश १",
 "2": "प्रदेश २",
 "3": "प्रदेश ३",
 "4": "प्रदेश ४",
 "5": "प्रदेश ५",
 "6": "प्रदेश ६",
 "7": "प्रदेश ७ "
}
```

I want to implement this json data in ng-options in select. I want to implement the key of this json data as the value of the select options and the value of the json data as the label of the select options. 
and here is my html code

```
<select ng-model= "province" aria-controls="example1" class="form-control form-control-sm" multiple="" ng-options=" x as value for (x, y) in optionData">
</select>
```

with this code i am only able to set either value or label at the single time. But I want to set both value and label at the same time. is there any way ?

Comment: Can you please create a working jsfiddle and share the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, change "value" to "y" in your NgOptions

```
ng-options="x as y for (x, y) in optionData"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using the `ng-repeat`

```
<select aria-controls="example1" class="form-control form-control-sm" multiple="" ><option ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" value="{{key}}">{{ value }}</option></select>
```

This method is listed in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat